# Filter data by multiple rows in second table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. users and users_meta. I want the query to return all users that have sexe=M and user_att1=1 (which should return only mathew) but I also need to be able to filter by other attributes as well.

`users` table is organized as such:

```
ID  | Firstname | Lastname  | Sexe     etc.
1      Mathew      Perkins     M
2      Andrea      Smith       F
3      Andrew      Story       M
```

`users_meta` table is organized as such:

```
ID  | user_id |  meta_key   | meta_value 
1   | 1       | user_att1   | 1
2   | 1       | user_att2   | 0
3   | 2       | user_att1   | 0
4   | 2       | user_att2   | 1
5   | 3       | user_att1   | 0
6   | 3       | user_att2   | 1
```

I tried using `group_concat` and `concat` and could not get the desired result.

This is my current query, which gives the desired output but I am not filtering by the attribute if that makes sense.

```
SELECT 
    users.id,users.firstname,
    users.lastname, 
    concat(users_meta.meta_value) as 'user_att1' 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_meta ON users.id=users_meta.user_id 
WHERE users_meta.meta_key='user_att1' 
GROUP BY users.id 
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Thanks for any help or pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your use case, I would use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname
FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_meta um ON um.user_id = u.id 
WHERE u.sexe = 'M'
GROUP BY u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname
HAVING MAX(um.meta_key = 'user_att1' AND um.meta_value = 1) > 0
ORDER BY u.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

The nice thing about this technique is that you can add more criteria on `users_meta.meta_key` simply by adding more conditions in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: need to rework to take into account multiple values, but this does exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are rather close.  The query would look like this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, 
       um.meta_value as user_att1
FROM users u JOIN
     users_meta um
     ON u.id = um.user_id AND
        um.meta_key = 'user_att1'  AND
        um.meta_value = '1'
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20 ;
```

No aggregation is necessary and if you want to filter by a value, the comparison should be in the `ON`, `WHERE`, or `HAVING` clauses.

Comment: How would this work if there are multiple attributes I need to check?

Comment: @user3404390 . . . For two or three attributes, you can add additional joins.  For more attributes, I would go with a different approach.  If you just need to filter the values, I would use `exists` in the `where` clause.  If you want to fetch them in the `select`, I would use conditional aggregation.